# std::async on member function of member field

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Foo
{

private:

    std::unique_ptr<Bar>& bar;
    int retVal;
    std::future<int> myFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, &Foo::bar->myMethod, this);

    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar>& bar_) : bar(bar_) {}

}
```

I believe this sums up the topic, as this doesn't work. How can I launch `myFuture` on `Bar::myMethod`?

Comment: If it's `Bar::myMethod` that should be launched, why do you try to pass `this` (a `Foo*`) as the object argument?

Comment: For starters, why is the template parameter of your future `retVal`? And these sort of issues can often be resolved by encapsulating the call in a lambda, although that might not even be necessary in this case.

Comment: Your member field is also not a `Bar`, but a `vector`, so very likely not gonna have a `myMethod`. I'm afraid the pseudo code doesn't sum it up to well. Would you consider elaborating more?

Comment: I fixed the code, thank you. Tried changing `this` to `bar` - doesn't work. I didn't catch any `vector` in this code.

Comment: Bah, `unique_ptr`, not vector. My eyes are not what they used to be

Comment: Oh, well yeah. But since this `unique_ptr` is a member of `Foo` I believe I should still pass `this` to `std::async, shouldn't I?

Comment: try this `std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar(new Bar)`

Comment: I can't, as it's a reference to `unique_ptr`

Comment: @galah92 no, you need to pass a `Bar *` or `Bar &`. `this` is a `Foo *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to name `Bar::myMethod`, and pass a  (cv appropriate) `Bar *` or `Bar &`. That will look something like

```
std::async(std::launch::async, &Bar::myMethod, bar.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, fixing some of the mess (i.e. adding everything that is missing) we can arrive at a simple solution using a lambda function:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
public:
    int myMethod(void) {
        std::cerr << "Hi!\n";
        return 1;
    }
};

class Foo {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar>& bar;
    int retVal;
    std::future<int> myFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, [this](void)->int{return bar->myMethod();});
public:
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar>& bar_) : bar(bar_) {}
};

int main(void) {
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    Foo foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

This might of course not be the only solution, nor the best in terms of performance.